# Delphi - How to do searching for incomplete string matches

Tags: string, delphi, search, fuzzy-search

I have a listing of approximately 300,000 businesses which is a varchar field in a small relational rdbms (ComponentAce's AbsoluteDB) The user needs to be able to search the name of the business, but the user probably doesn’t have the exact name.

For example, the name is *The National Bank of Kansas*

Ideally, the user could start typing National and have it find all strings that have National in it (notice it is NOT the first word)
I would love a way to allow the user to type “Nation Bank” (instead of National Bank) and still have this find the proper data.

In trying to figure this out, I think a text retrieval system is way more than I am looking for.  My WHOLE data file is approx 15 MB.  The overhead for a full text retrieval system is beyond what I need.  Is fuzzy searching, with some type of string similarity algorithm the way I want to go?  For example, something like DamerauLevenshtein?

Comment: Your best bet is to do some searching for "Full Text Search Delphi" on google and you will get a lot of results. This question is probably off topic as it is likely to result in a number of opinions and product suggestions. Another option is to look at soundex. There are a number of databases that include soundex query capabilities. For example, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions148.htm for Oracle and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx for SQL server. It ultimately depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: "I have a listing" is very vague. What container is that "listing" in? Is it in a text file, a database, or something else? The means of locating information varies widely based on how that information is stored. If it's not clear why that's relevant, call the nearest auto repair shop and ask them how much it will cost to replace the engine in a car, and see if they'll give you a "one size fits all" estimate; the cost is very different depending on whether you're driving a garden-variety sedan or a Ferrari. Please be specific about what it is you're asking here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. :-) I don't use Absolute DB, but AFAIK it supports SQL, which means it should support the `LIKE` operator with wildcards. Is that available in it's SQL grammar?

Comment: You basically have 4 options. LIKE, SOUNDEX (which AbsoluteDB doesn't appear to support), a Full Text Search engine like Rubicon or alternatively loading the entire set into memory and doing the soundex/searching yourself.

Comment: @Graymatter: Or a `LIKE '%National%'`, which of course won't use indexes and might be somewhat slower.

Comment: @KenWhite The problem with `LIKE '%National%'` is that it won't find something like `Nation Bank`. Another option is to store the Delphi Soundex of the name in another field in the DB and to search for that using a `LIKE`. The only problem with Soundex is that it's more suited to English names.

Answer (score 4):

The way I've solved this in the past is to create an inverted index, eliminating high-frequency words (a, and, the, with, etc.) and then either do:

1. linear matches based on what's typed for each word;
2. remove vowels; or
3. use Soundex.

Whether you do a search for each character that's entered or not is up to you, although this approach is ideal for real-time filtering. (The point is, you're not hitting the database on each character that's typed. You hit it after the first few characters then filter the rest from the results.)

I've done this with both in-memory search tables as well as using database tables.

For an inverted index, you break everything up into words and save a list of record numbers for each word. When the person types 'natio' it shows a list of all records that match any word that starts with the stem 'natio', like 'nation', 'nations', 'national', etc. So 'national' might be found in 25 records, 'nations' might be in 37, and 'nation' might be in 58. Obviously, the longer the stem, the fewer the hits.

If they enter multiple words, treat each word like a separate search, but AND the results together. So 'nation' and 'bank' would only show the results where both word stems are found together.

It's really not all that difficult. First make a list of all the words in the database along with their frequency counts. Eliminate all of the meaningless high-frequency words, and any others that aren't very meaningful. Then build an inverted index from the rest.

If the data changes very frequently, then keep the list of meaningless words around and rebuild your inverted index automatically after updating the inverted word index by removing these words first.

The result isn't all that big, and it should run quite fast if you implement it correctly.

I've never seen a situation where the use of SQL queries with LIKE in them ran anywhere near as fast as this approach.